# Программное нажатие на элементы Webview

Tags: java, android, парсер, jsoup, webview

Тренируюсь в создании парсера, работающего в приложении android и умеющего взаимодействовать с разбираемым сайтом. Не могу понять как сделать программное нажатие на один из элементов сайта. 
Код который собрал по старым темам отказывается нажимать на указанное поле:

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myWebView;
    TextView tView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new HtmlHandler(), "HtmlHandler");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                /*1*/myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('story__title')[3].click();");
                /*2*/myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:HtmlHandler.handleHtml(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");
        }});
                myWebView.loadUrl("https://m.pikabu.ru/");
}
class HtmlHandler {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void handleHtml(String html) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        final String title = doc.title();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tView.setText(title);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Причем код из строки 2 выполняется, но строка 1 с нажатием игнорируется.
Элемент на который хочу нажать:

```
    <h2 class="story__title">
<a href="https://pikabu.ru/story/kazusfaktor_6826047" class="story__title-link story__title-link_visited">Казус-фактор</a>
</h2>
```

Comment: Можно достать адрес ссылки и загрузить вручную через: `WebView.loadUrl();`

Comment: В данном примере сработает. Но мне нужна возможность взаимодействовать с элементами для которых не указана явная ссылка. Например href="javascript:;"

Comment: Тогда проверьте - есть ли на самом деле такой элемент в странице. И попробуйте выполнять скрипты методом [`WebView.evaluateJavascript (String, ValueCallback<String>)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%2520android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) Ещё, возможно, надо вызвать клик непосредственно у ссылки (элемента `<a ...>`)

Comment: Действительно document.getElementsByClassName('story__title') возвращает нулевую ссылку. Но почему так происходит, если я точно определил название класса для моб. версии?  https://i.paste.pics/f873b638d1e38953b2d87ecbd0b10cff.png

Comment: Вы выводите в `TextView` заголовок - выведите для теста там же весь код страницы (в лог, например) и посмотрите что там есть. Вообще парсить `html` чужого сайта дело неблагодарное я вам скажу - всё может "поломаться" в любой момент.

Comment: Пробывал. В строке (2) я вызываю метод handleHtml() передав ему весь показанный сайт как строку. Превратив полученную строку в Document и вызвав для него select(".story__title").size(). Я получаю число 20, т.е. классы с данным именем есть. Но в строке (1) где я ищу классы с таким же именем на той же странице метод getElementsByClassName('story__title') возвращает null, хотя описанная выше проверка показала что искомые поля есть

Comment: Забыл упомянуть ещё один нюанс: в `WebView`, особенно на старых Андроидах, версия `JS` и `DOM` может отличаться и то, что работает на десктопе в свежайшем браузере вполне может не работать в `WebView`,  потому что ,например, нет такой функции или атрибута. Подобные ошибки вроде должны выводиться в лог.

Comment: Девайс на котором запускаю программу достаточно новый. А в лог выводится только сообщение "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.jsoup.select.Elements.size ()' on a null object reference" где size() применяется к результату метода document.getElementsByClassName()

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96558/discussion-between-woesss-and-keker).